# Logstash - Create multiple events from xml file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to parse the xml elements into multiple events based on the  and , but while parsing it is given as a single event with array of values.

Sample XML:
*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT >
  <Header>
       <Info1>ABC</Info1>
       <Info2>123</Info2>
  </Header>
  <DataArea>
        <Data>
            <Text>T1</Text>
            <Value>V1</Value>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Text>T2</Text>
            <Value>V2</Value>
        </Data>
        <Data>
            <Text>T3</Text>
            <Value>V3</Value>
        </Data>
  </DataArea>
</ROOT>
```

*

I would like to get the output as
*

```
{
    "Info1":"ABC",
    "Info2":"123",
    "data.text":"T1",
    "data.value":"V1",
},
{
    "Info1":"ABC",
    "Info2":"123",
    "data.text":"T2",
    "data.value":"V2",
},
{
    "Info1":"ABC",
    "Info2":"123",
    "data.text":"T3",
    "data.value":"V3",
}
```

*

Logstash confg

*

```
input {
  stdin { }
}
filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false 
        xpath => [
            "//Header/Info1/text()","Info1",
            "//Header/Info2/text()","Info2",
            "//DataArea/Data/Text/text()","data.text",
            "//DataArea/Data/Value/text()","data.value"
            ]
        }
  }
}
output { elasticsearch { host => localhost } stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

**But I am getting the output as**

```
{
    "Info1":"ABC",
    "Info2":"123",
    "data.text":[
        [0] "T1",
        [1] "T2",
        [2] "T3"],
    "data.value":[
        [0] "V1",
        [1] "V2",
        [2] "V3"]
}
```

Please help me on how to write the proper xpath filter in order to parse it as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362303/logstash-split-event-from-an-xml-file-in-multiples-documents-keeping-informatio) looks pretty similar to yours and has an answer. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I think `Val` provided answer is more helpful to you...